# Is there a difference where the implicit intersection operator @ goes in an Excel formula with structured table references?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-tables

#### Context

I just received an update from Excel<sup>1</sup>, and now it's littering my formulas with the [implicit intersection operator (`@`)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34). Also in formulas that use structured table references like `table1[@Column1]`.

It transforms the latter to `@table1[@Column1]`.

I find that extra clutter hampers readability (my reason to use tables in the first place).

#### Attempts

I tried omitting the `@` between the brackets completely and found that below formulas all give the same result.

- What I'm used to: `table1[@Column1]`
- What Excel makes of it: `@table1[@Column1]`
- What I would be fine with: `@table1[Column1]`

As Excel insists on adding the `@` at the beginning of the reference I would be fine with using the second option `@table1[Column1]` throughout my worksheet. However, I am unsure if this will give me the same results as with the "old" way of referencing.

The [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34) seems not to have anything on that operator in combination with table references.

#### Question

Will only using the `@` operator at the start of the reference always give equal results to using the `@` operator right after the first square bracket in structured table references?

---

<sub>1: Version 2008, Build 13127.21506 Click-to-Run</sub>